# What is a term for functions that are equal when $x=f(x)$?

Tags: functions, terminology

Is there a term for functions that are equal for $f(f(x))=r(r(x))$, but $f(x)≠r(x)$?

If so what is that term?

This question was inspired by USAMTS Round 1.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the question. Equal to what?

Comment: Such functions are called *idempotent*.

Comment: $x$ is called a fixed point of $f$

Comment: I think idempotent is probably what you are looking for. Think of the projection operator as perhaps the easiest example.

Comment: What I mean is a situation where f(x) does not equal r(x), but f(f(x))=r(r(x))

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich, that is what I am looking for but I should have been more clear.

Comment: $f $ is not injektive

Comment: @Fred What is the relevance of that?